# Access query with Count()

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

(Access 2010)

Can anyone tell the reason why column 2 and 3 retrieve exactly the same numbers? (they should not - different conditions and consequently different number of records)

Cannot see what's wrong...

```
SELECT tblAssssDB.[Division:], Count(([Mod New Outcome]="SELF EMPLOYED" And [ET Outcome]="GREY AREA")) AS [Undecided to Self-employed], Count(([Mod New Outcome]="EMPLOYED" And [ET Outcome]="GREY AREA")) AS [Undecided to Employed], Count(([Mod New Outcome]="SELF EMPLOYED" And [tblAssssDB].[ET Outcome]="EMPLOYED")) AS [Employed to Self-Employed], Count((IsNull([ET Outcome] And [ET Outcome]=[Mod New Outcome]))) AS [No change in Outcome]
FROM tblAssssDB
WHERE (((tblAssssDB.[ET Comment]) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY tblAssssDB.[Division:];
```

Help!!

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is doing that literally, it is counting how many records are there. so you have to use a condition to count. See the answer by @Davis that will do what you want

Answer (score 3):

Count is not really intended to be used to give you a quantity of specific outcomes.  I think that you would be better served by using something like this

```
SUM(IIF(critiera, 1, 0))
```

Comment: This is what I had earlier but would not worked either.I am fixing the work of a previous developer who created an excel linked Table (an Excel spreadsheet on Sharepoint).
I am getting the impression that my code is good but the Excel messes everything? Anyone ever worked on that architecture? 
(apparently the worst I have ever seen IN MY LIFE!)

Comment: What result are you getting?  Does the query fail, give you an unexpected value or anything of the like?  I would examine the expressions you are using.  The one used for [No change in Outcome] does not appear to be valid.

Comment: I have used linked spreadsheets on network shares without any strange issues.  If you are concerned that it is causing an issue you can create a query to insert the records into a local temp table and query from it.

Comment: I basically get for all columns, a count of all the records. This means none of the conditions/criteria are been taken into consideration. Never seen that before. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking to build the tables into Access just for the trial and error of the the script.

Comment: That seems to indicate that something in the criteria is causing the outcome to always be true.  Check the logic with several examples to confirm it will function as expected.